# Set a minimum execution time for a command

Tags: linux, bash

This might be an odd question, but is there a way to set a minimum execution time for a command in Bash?
For example:

```
command1
command2
command3
```

In one such case, I need at least 3 seconds to elapse between `command1` and `command3`, but `command2` will take an unknown (but finite) amount of time. If `command2` takes, say, 1 second, then I would want a delay of 2 additional seconds before executing `command3`. If `command2` takes, say, 4 seconds, then I would want no additional delay before `command3`.

Currently, I am inserting a `/bin/sleep 3` command before `command3` in order to guarantee a delay of at least 3 seconds. This works, but a cleaner and more time-efficient solution would be fantastic.

I appreciate any ideas; I'm not a pro with Bash and so I worry I might be either missing something basic, or asking for something overly complicated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it simple? Like: Get current time and save it. Do the task. Substract current time from saved time. If the difference is lower then 3 seconds, then substract the difference from 3 and wait.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to extract useful information from the `time` command without doing something convoluted and inelegant, so I figured it probably wasn't meant to be used that wait.

Comment: `useful information from the time` time is not needed. To get current time, with nanosecond resolution, use `date +%s.%N`

Comment: Oh jeez, that never even crossed my mind to use `date`, oof. I am glad I ended up asking here though, the answer from "that other guy" is really nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a trivial way to do it:

```sh
command1
sleep 3 &   # Start a 3s sleep in the background
command2
wait        # Wait for the background sleep to finish (if it hasn't already)
command3
```

If `command2` takes more than three seconds, then the sleep will already have exited, and the `wait` will return immediately.

If `command2` takes less than three seconds, then `wait` will wait for the sleep to exit, which it will do after a total of 3s after being started.

Comment: Wow, that is clever as heck, thanks! I made sure to test it for myself and it works perfectly, thank you! I've used the `&` like that before, but never knew about `wait`, so I learned something new \o/